# What's the best way to not include my own package in a requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, setuptools

I wrote an ETL pipeline as a Python package that can be installed in and ran from a remote machine. To test it out before I deploy, I install and run it locally. An annoying little pet peeve is having to delete the package itself from `requirements.txt` every time I update my dependencies, I've forgotten to do this once or twice and it's caused problems.  All my packages are installed with conda, so I run `conda list --export > requirements.txt` to create the dependency list. Is there some smarter, more foolproof way to just not include my package in its own dependency list?

Bonus question: given I've installed my dependencies with `conda`, is it wrong to install my own package with `pip install .`?

Comment: I am not sure that helps you, but did you know you can `pip install -e .` inside your python project, so that this project folder is now linked to your environment? Every change in project is immediately visible, so you don't need to "install" it again for testing

Comment: I did not know that, that's really good to know, thank you!